# How to optimize Plutus smart contracts?

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, on-chain

## Context

I'm creating scripts with hardcoded parameters in my smartcontract and I would like to reduce footprint of them to reduce transaction fees. Right now i'm doing so using *parameterized smartcontracts*. I can't provide source but I read or heard somewhere that using *parameterized smartcontracts* use up a lot of **ExMemory**. When building plutus scripts i'm using `evaluateScriptCounting` which after compilation shows me **ExCPU** and **ExMemory** of my script. So far I have found the only way to hardcode parameters without using *parameterized smartcontracts* with `BuiltinByteString`s is doing something like this:

```
{-# INLINABLE flattenBuiltinByteString #-}
flattenBuiltinByteString :: [BuiltinByteString] -> BuiltinByteString
flattenBuiltinByteString [] = emptyByteString 
flattenBuiltinByteString (x:xs) = appendByteString x (flattenBuiltinByteString xs)

{-# INLINABLE getPkh #-}
getPkh :: PubKeyHash
getPkh = PubKeyHash { getPubKeyHash = flattenBuiltinByteString [ consByteString x emptyByteString |x <- [128,164,244,91,86,184,141,17,57,218,35,188,76,60,117,236,109,50,148,60,8,127,37,11,134,25,60,167]]}
```

I was expecting that this way I would get lower **ExCPU** and **ExMemory** units. But I did some tests and to my surprise my smartcontract without parameterized parameters was bigger!

## Tests

1. ExCPU -> 8366313, ExMemory -> 28200. Plain always succeeds.
2. ExCPU -> 8366313, ExMemory -> 28200. BuiltinByteString, no checks, no datum.
3. ExCPU -> 9080865, ExMemory -> 30600. Parameterized no checks, no datum.
4. ExCPU -> 9438141, ExMemory -> 31800. Parameterized no checks, added typed datum with 4 fields.
5. ExCPU -> 10152693, ExMemory -> 34200. Parameterized 4 checks against typed datum.
6. ExCPU -> 11135202, ExMemory -> 37500. BuiltinByteString 4 checks against typed datum.

## Questions

1. My `flattenBuiltinByteString` is doing the flattening `foldr` style which is ineffective and I suppose is why i'm having such big jump in **ExMemory** units. I was looking for `foldl'` in Plutus library but couldn't find anything. Does Plutus have something simillar to `seq` so that I could make my own `foldl'` implementation?
2. Are there other more effective ways to flatten `BuiltinByteString` list on-chain?
3. What over tricks I could do besides using `BuiltinData` types instead of my own custom typed data types to optimize my smartcontracts?
4. Should I even be bothering with optimizations like this, whats the upper **ExCPU** and **ExMemory** limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am building a dApp myself and I am running into similar issues related to hitting the current mainnet's `maxTxExUnits` upper boundaries of `exUnitsMem` and `exUnitsSteps`.

**In regards to question 4**:

You can find the current upper limits by querying your cardano node for protocol parameters like so:

```
cardano-cli query protocol-parameters $MAGIC --out-file protocol-parameters.json
```

The limits can be found under: `maxTxExecutionUnits`

I resolved some of my issues related to exceeding the ExMemory upper limit by:

- simplifying/ optimizing the contract logic
- removing `traceIfFalse` statements or at least decreasing long log message string down to error codes
- using **Bang Pattern** in let-bindings
- avoid exhaustive case patterns and instead rely on Plutus' throwing an error for a missing pattern match

There are many more resources you can read below for further possible code improvements to optimize your script.

Sources:

- [MinSwap Article](https://minswap-labs.medium.com/tech-drips-1-optimizing-plutus-script-to-reduce-fees-and-increase-throughput-db6cce65c959)
- [Plutonomicon](https://github.com/Plutonomicon/plutonomicon/blob/main/scriptmem.md)

Comment: The biggest decrease in mem usage I was able to achieve is by pattern matching against function inputs - especially when it comes to ScriptContext.
Try to always pattern match unless you really need every field inside a given type. Good examples for that are `TxOut`, `Maybe` types and any of your datums

Answer (score 1):

Mlabs created excelent tool to quickly check and analyse size of smartcontracts. Github repo is [here](https://github.com/mlabs-haskell/plutus-simple-model)